# shuffle JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle

Hy guys. I am making a game of Memory and to achieve that I had to somehow shuffle images in Array. I found an old answer on Stack Overflow, Fisher–Yates shuffle, and used that, and it works but I don't understand how. Can someone explain step by step and what each element represents in this code. Especially first line, how are there three values in a variable. Thank you.

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
```

Used like so:

```
var arr = [2, 11, 37, 42];
arr = shuffle(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Comment: There aren't three values in the first line, but 3 different variables declared,  where only the first is initialized with the arrays length

Comment: The answer in the duplicate includes resources about Fisher-Yates. On a more general note, since that algorithm is well known, you can just google it to find out more. It even has a Wikipedia page.

Comment: The var keyword is used to declare one or more variables in the given scope (here, the shuffle functions scope). Doing "var a, b, c;" is essentially the same as doing "var a; var b; var c;" but shorter. You can assign a value with the "=" syntax, such as "var a = 'hello', b;" which again is the same as "var a = 'hello'; var b;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break it into parts. Let's say the array length is `n`.
We are starting with `currentIndex = n`, and we will continue until `currentIndex = 0`, which means that all elements have been iterated upon and moved to some location with a probability.

Getting inside the loop, the first line has two functions

- `Math.random()`: Generates a random real number in `range [0, 1)`. Yes it's open at 1, so it doesn't generate 1 ever
- `Math.floor()`: Gives the integer part of the real number given to it as a parameter

Now observe, `Math.random()*currentIndex` will generate a random number in `range [0, n)` (basic multiplication). `Math.floor()` will take the integer part, so we will have an integer between `{0, 1, 2, ... n-1}`. This value is randomIndex.

Now we are simply swapping the numbers at currentIndex and randomIndex. We do this for all elements starting from the end. So the array is shuffled.

However, this is not a very good shuffling algorithm as you are reducing the scope of randomness with each iteration. A better shuffle would be to bind the numbers in pairs with random numbers, and then sort the pairs with those bound random numbers as keys, and get rid of them to have your original array of numbers shuffled.

Answer (score 0):

The first line is actually just shorthand for writing out three variables:

So, this:

```
var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
```

Translates to:

```
var currentIndex = array.length;   // 4
var temporaryValue;                // undefined
var randomIndex;                   // undefined
```

Comment: Erm, `currentIndex` will be a number, not the array.

Comment: @vlaz Thanks. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
```

There are no 3 values in one variable, just 3 variables declared with one initialized and the others are `undefined`. Better format the code like this:

```
var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue,
    randomIndex;
```

---

```
while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    // ...
    currentIndex -= 1;
    // ...
}
```

currentIndex is going from `array.length` to `0`, so `array.length` iterations

---

```
randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
```

random number from `0` to `currentIndex - 1`

---

```
temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
```

swaps the elements at position `randomIndex` and `currentIndex`.

This should give you the basics to understand this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="result">

<script>
var arrayList= ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'];
arrayList.sort(function(){
    return 0.5 - Math.random()
})

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML  = arrayList;

</script>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.